# How can I change customswitch label on/off in reactstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reactstrap

I use reactstrap customswitch in my project. How can  I change label on/off?

```
const ProfileSwitch = ({title, text, name, id, label}) => {
    return <div className="profile-switch">
        <div className="profile-switch__text">
            <p>{title}</p>
            <span>{text}</span>
        </div>
        <CustomInput type="switch" id={id} name={name} label={label} />
    </div>
}

export default ProfileSwitch;
```

Comment: what do you mean by label on/off, please elaborate?

Comment: Where do the `props` come from? Are `title, text, name, id, label` stored in state?

Comment: @AbuSufian my english not well. https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-bash-ntd6e?file=/src/switch.js:349-355 here yo can look, i want when checkbox unchecked, label text change to off

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros here you can look  codesandbox.io/s/crimson-bash-ntd6e?file=/src/switch.js:349-355

Comment: That's fine, the question is how you handle the on/off state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this situation with toggle and useState.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CustomInput } from "reactstrap";

const ProfileSwitch = ({ title, text, name, id, label }) => {
  const [isToggled, setToggled] = useState(false);
  const toggleTrueFalse = () => setToggled(!isToggled);

  return (
    <div className="profile-switch">
      <div className="profile-switch__text">
        <p>{title}</p>
        <span>{text}</span>
      </div>
      <CustomInput
        onClick={toggleTrueFalse}
        type="switch"
        id={id}
        name={name}
        label={isToggled === true ? "on" : "off"}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfileSwitch;

ProfileSwitch.defaultProps = {
  title: "title",
  text: "text"
};
```

I've forked your code, so here's the solution on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-checkbox-on-off-1z5o5?file=/src/switch.js:0-699)